# Loading module variables in Dojo?

Tags: dojo

I'm new to dojo and can't figure out why this is happening

in dojo.html:

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom", "dojo/domReady!", "a" ], function(query, a) {
            query("#greeting").style("color", "red");
            alert(a.sheep);
        });
```

in a.js

```
define([], function() {
var a = {
    "sheep": "blah",
}
return a;
});
```

Requiring and loading module a is fine, but when I try to alert a.sheep, I get undefined.
Note: I've also tried declaring sheep : "blah" as well and try changing sheep to an alert function and running a.sheep; which worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you cannot access `a.sheep` is that there is `dojo/NodeList-dom` module in `a` variable. The order of elements in `define/require` array is bind to the list of arguments in the subsequent `function`. So you should write:

```
require(["dojo/query", "a", "dojo/NodeList-dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query, a) {

})
```

Also from the practical point of view I happen to format my code like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/query",

    "a",

    "dojo/NodeList-dom",
    "dojo/domReady!"
],
function(
    declare
    query,

    a
){

return declare(null, {

    constructor: function() {}

});
});
```

Every module on his own line, plus logical clustering of modules via empty lines.